# tf.cond lowers the training speed

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I was using `tensorflow` input pipelines like `cifar10` model in `tensorflow` and try to use `tf.cond` to do validation and I wrote something like this

```
train_data = model.input(istrain=True)
val_data = model.input(istrain=False)

# This selects which stream to use.
select_val = tf.placeholder(dtype=bool,shape=[],name='select_test')
data = tf.cond(
    select_val,
    lambda:val_data,
    lambda:train_data
)

# Here is the model.
loss = ...
train_op = ...
...

with tf.Session():
    ...
```

And if I delete the cond and just use the training data, the speed is 4000 samples/s and if I use the code above, the speed decrease to 2300 samples/s. The validation pipeline capacity is set really small so it won't take too much memory in GPU. The frequency of doing validation is also really low. 
I'm not sure what is going wrong and please help me out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tf.cond` is not fully lazy. Any operations that are required by either of the branches of the `cond` will be run even if the branch that requires it is not the branch to be executed. So in your case, both `model.input(istrain=True)` and `model.input(istrain=False)` are being execute every time your `data` op is being called. The results of one of them is just ignored.

The [documentation for `cond`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond) gives a minimal code example:

> Note that the conditional execution applies only to the operations
>   defined in fn1 and fn2. Consider the following simple program:
>
> ```
> z = tf.multiply(a, b)
> result = tf.cond(x < y, lambda: tf.add(x, z), lambda: tf.square(y))
> ```
>
> If x < y, the tf.add operation will be executed and tf.square
>   operation will not be executed. Since z is needed for at least one
>   branch of the cond, the tf.mul operation is always executed,
>   unconditionally. Although this behavior is consistent with the
>   dataflow model of TensorFlow, it has occasionally surprised some users
>   who expected a lazier semantics.

Also note, this means that if your `model.input` is pulling some set of data from a larger pool (say, a batch from an entire dataset), each time the `cond` is run, data gets pulled from both validation and training, and one set just gets thrown away. This can cause problems more serious than inefficiencies in some cases. For example, if you're processing only a certain number epochs, then with this code you're not actually processing that number of epochs because data was being pulled that was not used.

Comment: Thanks bro, this is really a detailed and clear explanation. And now I'm using `sess.run` to get training set and validation set respectively, and `sess.run(..., feed_dict={})` to feed back the dataset. I'm not sure if it there is a better way.

Comment: @zhr1201: Another option is sharing your variables (see [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variable_scope)). The way this works is you build the network twice, but tell them to share variables (weights, etc). Then one gets the training as input and the other gets the validation as input. Then you can just run the ops in the network you want, but both are trained together.